# Outputting less white space per line

Tags: c++

My current output is:

```
  /\
  /\
  /\
```

I need it to be:

```
  /\
 /\
/\
```

My current code:

```
    cout << "What size? ";

    int input;
    cin >> input;

    int counter = 1;
    while(counter <= input){
        std::cout 
          << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(input) 
          << "/" << "\\" 
          << std::endl;
        counter++;
    }
```

I outputted the pattern with the width of the input, which I put as 3, but I don't know how to fill with less whitespace to acheive the pattern.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. This is not Java

Comment: `std::setw(input)` uses the same value every iteration through the loop.  That doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: You could drop all of the formatting you're doing now in `std::cout` and simply output `std::string(input-counter, ' ')` in the `std::cout` line.

Comment: Interesting. Two people thought it's worth to answer this question, but zero people thought it's worth an upvote...

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks for the reminder. Upvoted now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `std::setw(input)` you need to decrease `input`:

```cpp
std::cout << std::setfill(' ');
while (input-- > 0) {
    std::cout << std::setw(input) << "" << "/\\\n";
}
```

Note that I use an empty C string (`""`) as the first output after `setw`. Otherwise the `/` you had as the first output will mess up the formatting and it'd become:

```
 /\
/\
/\
```

Also note that `std::setfill` is persistent so you only need to set it once and it will stay the same until you set it to something else.